# projection of a random vector and angle?

Tags: probability, concentration-of-measure, large-deviation-theory

I have a random vector $v$ whose expected squared projection length along a unit vector $\hat{u}$ is large, while the expected squared length is small, i.e. $\mathbf{E}[|<v,\hat{u}>|^2]$ is large and $\mathbf{E}[||v||^2]$ is small. Does this imply that the angle between $v$ and $\hat{u}$ is small?

Without the probablistic assumption, if the projection of a vector along a direction is large and its length is small, then  the cosine of the angle is  large, which in turn imply that the angle is small. Does this remain true in the probabilitic setting?

Comment: What do you mean by "large" and "small" here? Isn't your "large" *smaller* than your "small"?

Comment: Suppose the squared projection is at least $A$, and the square of the length is at most $B$. Then the square of the cosine of the angle is at least $\frac{A}{B}$.

Comment: I understand that. I wonder what you *quantitatively*  mean by "large" and "small" in your question, esp. since $\langle v, \hat{u}\rangle^2 \leq \lVert v\rVert^2$ (always). For instance, assume wlog that $\mathbb{E}[\lVert v\rVert^2]=1$. Can you quantitatively rephrase your question in terms of the single parameter left?

Comment: That should work. The main motivation for the question is that, is the expected value of ratio of two r.v is related to the ratio of expectations. And is there any lower bound analog of Markov’s inequality?

Comment: I will try to explain myself later today

Comment: If I understand correctly your "lower bound analogue of Markov": yes if the non-negative r.v. is bounded a.s. (if $X\leq B$ a.s., just apply Markov to $B-X$). If you have higher moments, there is [Paley-Zygmund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality).

Comment: Thanks. PZ slipped my mind